# Owl carousel flickering first slide when randomising

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a carousel using owl carousel (I believe its v1.3.3) which will randomise and shuffle slides. I've managed to find someone else on here that has done that using the below code. The problem is that it flickers the first slide for a second before it randomises them and i was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to fix it or why it might happen? I've given the slides a class of randomise so that i can set anything without randomise to be static.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var owl = $('.randomise');
(function($){
     $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
           },
           shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
              allElems.splice(random, 1);
               return randEl;
           });
        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        }); 
        return $(shuffled);
    };
})(jQuery);
// Replace first class in function below if you have a custom class for your owl slider.
// Replace second class with the class or element tag for each the items of slider.
// using an extra class such as randomise means we can only add that class to the carousel items that we wish to shuffle.
$(function () {
    $(".randomise").shuffle();
    owl.owlCarousel();
      });
};
```